# Acceso a bases de datos con Zend Framework 2 en el modelo

Tags: php, base-de-datos, zend

Quería hacer una consulta acerca del acceso a bases de datos utilizando Zend Framework 2.

Estoy familiarizado con el uso de `ServiceManager` y como se realiza la configuración en `global.php`, `Module.php` para acceder a la base de datos a partir del controlador.

Mi actual problema es: ¿Hay alguna forma de realizar este acceso sin necesidad de utilizar el `ServiceManager` en el controlador y mandar el `Adapter` como argumento de entrada al modelo?

Es decir, ¿Puedo "llamar" al adaptador con la configuración de acceso a la base de datos desde el modelos desde el que voy a hacer uso para escribir código SQL directamente?

Answer (score -1):

Visita [esta dirección](http://victorroblesweb.es/2014/04/26/crud-con-zend-framework-2/) tal vez te sirva para lo que tu estas preguntando.